# Razor Foreach Loop not returning all data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I have a foreach loop that builds hyperlinks based on the number of items in the model.  It's working fine, except the part that says: `ProgramId = @item.ProgramIds.First()` is only returning the first program ID for each ProgramType.  What is the syntax for letting it loop through all of the program ID's rather than just the first?

```
@model IEnumerable<CMESurvey.ViewModels.ProgramTypeViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{ 
    <h2>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramTypes)</h2> 

    <ul>
        @foreach (var ProgramTitles in item.ProgramTitles)
        {
            <li>

                @Html.ActionLink(@ProgramTitles, "Results", "SurveyResponse", new { ProgramId = @item.ProgramIds.First() }, null)
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

}

```
   public class ProgramTypeViewModel
    {
        public int ProgramTypeIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> ProgramTitles { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<int> ProgramIds { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> ProgramTypes { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller action:

```
 public ViewResult Home()
        {
            var data = from SurveyProgramModel in surveyProgramRepository.Get()
                       group SurveyProgramModel by SurveyProgramModel.ProgramTypeId into programTypeGroup
           select new ProgramTypeViewModel()
           {

               ProgramTypeIds = programTypeGroup.Key,
               ProgramIds = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramId),
               ProgramTitles = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramTitle),
               ProgramTypes = programTypeGroup.Select(r => r.ProgramType.ProgramType).Distinct(),
           };

            return View(data);
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't understand why you'd want a list at that moment. After getting all the Program ID, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not explaining this very well.  ProgramIds is currently in a list.  I need to display the corresponding ProgramIds for each Program Title that it is looping through.  With  my current syntax, it is only returning the first ProgramId for each title, rather than the corresponding programID.  If I take out the 'first' syntax, I get 'Results?ProgramId=System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]' as my parameter.

Comment: Could you edit your question to add some information about your model? I still can't understand how comes a ProgramType has multiple IDs and so on. A class diagram for ProgramTypeViewModel would be of much help.

Comment: OK, I have added the data model and controller action for this view

Comment: Ok, so see if I understand your model, according to thwe query: each ProgramTypeViewModel has 1 ProgramTypeIds, 1 ProgramIds, 1 ProgramTitles and a list of ProgramTypes. Is that right?

Comment: It should produce a list of each individual ProgramType, and a Program type has an <li> of all the ProgramTitles.  That <li> element needs to be an actionlink that directs to page with the corresponding programId for that ProgramTitle.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little bit confused with your model and query. As far as I can understand, there should be a relationship between program and type, which there isn't.

So, I'd strongly recommend you to review your viewmodel and its query.

However, see if this helps:

```
@foreach (var currentProgramTypeViewModel in Model)
        { 
            foreach(string currentProgramType in currentProgramTypeViewModel.ProgramTypes)
            {
                <h2>@currentProgramType</h2> 

                <ul>
                    @for (int mProgramIndex = 0; mProgramIndex < currentProgramTypeViewModel.ProgramIds.Count(); mProgramIndex++)
                    {
                        var programTitle = currentProgramTypeViewModel.ProgramTitles.ToList<string>()[mProgramIndex];
                        var programId = currentProgramTypeViewModel.ProgramIds.ToList<int>()[mProgramIndex];
                        <li>
                            @Html.ActionLink(programTitle, "Results", "SurveyResponse", new { ProgramId = programId }, null)
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting: CS0019: Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'method group'
and cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type system.collections.generic IEnumerable<int>

Comment: Beautiful!  That seems to have done the trick.  I owe you a beer.

Answer (score 3):

`item` refers to the value from the outer loop.  It looks like you want to use the value from the inner loop:

```
@foreach (var ProgramTitles in item.ProgramTitles)         
{             
    foreach(var programId in item.ProgramIds)
    {

       <li>                  
           @Html.ActionLink(ProgramTitles, "Results", "SurveyResponse", new { ProgramId = programId  }, null)             
       </li>         
    }
}
```

After you supplied the viewModel, it looks like you have ProgramTitles and ProgramIds as two disconnected arrays. Maybe, what you have is that an item at array index n for ProgramTitle has a corresponding entry in the nth item of the ProgramIds array. The viewModel can be improved, but this is my solution to that:

```
@for (var index = 0; index < item.ProgramTitles.Count; index++)         
{             

       <li>                  
           @Html.ActionLink(ProgramTitles[index], "Results", "SurveyResponse", new {  ProgramId = item.ProgramIds[index]}, null)             
       </li>         
}
```

Comment: Hmm...  Well that fixed the number issue, but every ProgramType with more than 1 ProgramTitle is showing up twice.

Comment: I have added the ViewModel and controller action if that makes any more sense.

Comment: You aren't deduping/distinct-ing them.